# Vim: Pathogen not loading

Tags: vim, pathogen

I've recently moved to a new MacBook, taking my vim dot files with me. Whilst Pathogen works fine on my old MacBook, it's not loading at all on my new one. I've now reinstalled Pathogen from scratch and it's not working with the most basic setup either. I've tried both iTerm and Terminal.app in case it was the newer version of iTerm I'm running that was the issue.

[.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/1558961)

[.vim](https://gist.github.com/1558958)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: The directory hierarchy of .vim shows that it contains your `.vimrc` file, which should normally stay at your $HOME dir (as explained at `:help startup`). Thus it is possible that your .vimrc is not being loaded at all. You can check this with commands `:scriptnames` and `:version`.

Comment: I have that vimrc file symlinked to the $HOME dir as .vimrc. I just keep it in with the dot files so that I can version control it. Thanks for checking though, I should maybe have mentioned that :)

Answer (score 15):

OK, this is a bit embarrassing :$

As it turns out mMontu gave me the prod in the right direction by suggesting running `:scriptnames`. When I ran this I noticed that I was missing a heap of scripts but not all of them. I then looked at the dir structure I'd pasted earlier and noticed that a lot of the bundles were missing any files below them. It's because they'd not committed to my version control as they were already versioned repos. Doh! Recloned the repos and now all is well.

Thanks, mMontu! :)

Comment: And me also! Note that the solution to keep your bundle nicely in your personal repo is to use git submodule as it is designed to nest git repo in another git repo. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/