# E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim, zsh

I have Solarized installed via pathogen and it's been working fine in both terminal and MacVim on my Mac. Today, I tried setting up an Ubuntu box on Linode. I just cloned [my dotfiles](https://github.com/dtuite/dotfiles) and symlinked to my `.vim` and `.vimrc` folders (this is the same setup as I use on my local machine.

Whenever I try to run vim on the Ubuntu box I get an error

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line   43:
E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I can tell my `.vimrc` is being loaded because all other setting like line numbers are working.

The related lines in `.vimrc` are the following:

```
" settings needed for solarized colorscheme
syntax enable
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

This is the setup of my `.vim/bundle` directory (incase you suspect I don't actually have solzrized in there!):

```
~  ls .vim/bundle 
ack                  coffeescript         liquid               snipmate             vim-colors-solarized vim-jst              zencoding
closetag             html5.vim            nerdtree             surround             vim-javascript       vim-rails
```

One other thing, running `echo &t_Co` in vim on the ubunto box gets me `256`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know that it is kind of obvious, but did you check the contents of `~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized`? Just in case you are running in the same issue described in [Vim: Pathogen not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723464/vim-pathogen-not-loading/8735115#comment10887397_8735115)

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that this is the correct answer. I wasn't using submodules to manage my bundles which meant that the vim bundles were not cloned when I cloned my dotfiles. The bundle directories were present but empty.

Answer (score 48):

I was running into this problem just now, too.  I had my `call pathogen#infect()` line in my .vimrc just fine, but was getting the

> E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized

error, like you.  I moved my `call pathogen#infect()` up to the top of my .vimrc and all is swell now.  Try that if you're still having problems!

Comment: In my case "call pathogen#infect()" had been commented out when I pasted it into my .vimrc  I uncommented it and now everything works.

Comment: for those using janus + pathogen, insert settings after `call janus#load_pathogen`

Comment: Same for Vundle: insert the `call vundle#end()` line immediately after the `Plugin [...]` lines and before the settings (i.e. `colorscheme solarized`).

Answer (score 8):

```
:colo[rscheme] {name}   Load color scheme {name}.  This searches 'runtimepath'
            for the file "colors/{name}.vim.  The first one that
            is found is loaded.
```

You should put `solarized.vim` in `~/.vim/colors/`.

Comment: But then I won't be able to manage it with [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) right? According to the [Solarized website](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), not only should it work with solarized in the `bundle` directory, it is the recommended approach.

Comment: Maybe `pathogen` is not loaded properly. You should check `:set rtp?`.

Comment: Looks ok to me? `runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/ack,~/.vim/bundle/closetag,~/.vim/bundle/coffeescript,~/.vim/bundle/html5.vim,~/.vim/bundle/liquid,~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree,~/.vim/bundle/snipmate,~/.vim/bundle/su
rround,~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized,~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript,~/.vim/bundle/vim-jst,~/.vim/bundle/vim-rails,~/.vim/bundle/zencoding,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/
vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did;

```
cp ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself on a new CentOS box where 'vi' was mapped to a version of VIM without syntax support (ie. `-syntax`) and was giving the `E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized` error, while 'vim' mapped to a version with syntax support and worked fine with solarized.

Aliasing 'vi' to 'vim' resolved the issue.

For reference:

To check if the version of vim that you are running has support for syntax highlighting, run `:version` from within vim.  `-syntax` means no support, `+syntax` means it has support.

To create the alias, append `alias vi='vim'` to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

To re-source, type `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`, whichever is appropriate for your setup.

Answer (score 2):

One step you might be missing is to add

call pathogen#infect()

to your .vimrc file.

Src: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem and I fixed it by issuing

```
cd ~/.yadr
git pull
rake update
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it ;)

Found this bug:

https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/104

```
cp ~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/colors/solarized.vim ~/.vim/colors/
```

Comment: This requires manual updating, which is really overkill when there's [an actual solution](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/104#issuecomment-71037368) to it in the same issue, which was posted 2 years before you posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

As [Ryan Ransford said](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/104#issuecomment-71037368):

With the new version of `vundle` (Vundle.vim),

it appears as though "`colorscheme solarized`" must

come somewhere after "`call vundle#end()`".

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and resolve it *after* moving color setting after `call vundle#end()` in `~/.vimrc`

```yaml
...
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

if has('gui_running')
  set background=dark
  colorscheme solarized
else
  colorscheme zenburn
endif
```