# E185 error on mac terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, color-scheme

So I have given up and now seeking help! Anyway, I have tried to get a colorscheme going for my vim and am failing miserably. I will be using moloakai for now and I keep getting the E185 error. My .vimrc file looks like this:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme molokai
```

my molokai vim file is in `~/.vim/colors`

I also checked the runtime path and got this:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim72,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

Comment: Also: [Vim: “E185: Cannot find color scheme solarized”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15312357).

Comment: Are you actually using pathogen?

Comment: @FDinoff “my molokai vim file is in `~/.vim/colors`” and “I also checked the runtime path and got this: …” clearly indicates that pathogen or other path/plugin manager is not used.

Comment: @ZyX Thats what I thought but it seemed that the duplicates that glts pointed to were about pathogen